# How to mix two results in SQL (example included)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a mix of data this way:

Table A:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table B:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Mix into:

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
4
d
5
e
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sorting problem:

```
select col
from ((select col, 1 as which, row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum
       from a
      ) union all
      (select col, 2 as which, row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum
       from b
      )
     ) ab
order by seqnum, which
```

Comment: Assuming that columns in A and B have the same Data Type.

Comment: @PM77-1 . . . That is a necessary assumption for the OPs results.  This comment should be on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT mycol FROM (
    SELECT 1 seq, mycolA AS mycol, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mycolA) AS rn 
    FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, mycolB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY mycolB)
    FROM tableB
) x 
ORDER BY rn, seq
```